# Is there a way to to setup airflow dags such that dag-a won't run if dag-b is still running and vice versa?

Tags: airflow

I have multiple dags that run on different cadence: some weekly, some daily etc. I want it to setup such that while dag-a is running, dag-b should wait until it is completed. Also, if dag-b is running dag-a should wait until dag-b completes, etc. Is there a way to do this in airflow out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably the [ExternalTaskSensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor/index.html)

Airflow's [Cross-DAG Dependencies](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/operator/external.html) description is also pretty useful.

If you are using this, there is also the [Airflow DAG dependencies plugin](https://github.com/ms32035/airflow-dag-dependencies), which can be pretty useful for visualizating those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the sensor operator to sense the dag runs or a task in a dag run. External task sensor is the best bet. Be careful how you set the timedelta passed. In general, the idea is to specify the when should the sensor be able to find the dag run.
Eg:
If the main dag is scheduled at 4 UTC, and a task sensor is a task in the dag like below

```
ExternalTaskSensor(
            dag=dag,
            task_id='dag_sensor_{}'.format(key),
            external_dag_id=key,
            timedelta=timedelta(days=1),
            external_task_id=None,
            mode='reschedule',
            check_existence=True
        )
```

Then the other dag that should get sensed must be triggering a run at 4.00UTC. That one day difference is set to offset the difference of execution date and current date